# Импорт из соседнего приложения Django помечен как ошибка

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

Импорт из соседнего приложения Django помечен как ошибка:

"Import "app_1.models" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)".

И хотя все прекрасно импортируется и работает, но это мозолит глаза.
Работаю в Visual Studio Code с установленным Pylance. Есть идеи как поправить это?

Структура проекта стандартная, что-то вроде этого (названия условные):

```
|project
|
|__app_1__|
|         |_models.py
|__app_2__|
|         |_models.py
|__project
```

в app_2/models.py (подчеркнуто желтым курсивом):

```
from app_1.models import Partner
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, решил проблему таким образом:

```
from app_1.models import Partner # type: ignore
```

`# type: ignore` комментарий говорит Pylance игнорировать строку. Может быть кому-то еще это будет нужно здесь.